# upload media files, able to upload music and image files but not for video files

Tags: php, ajax, video, file-upload

I'd like to upload all media files using ajax+php..

if I upload image and music file everything working as fine.
so I try upload video, it fails. what's wrong??

here is my ajax

```
function uploadFile() {
    var file = document.getElementById("inputFile").files[0];
    var quest_ID = document.getElementById("questionnaireID").value;
    var quest_Number = document.getElementById("questNum").value;
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("inputFile", file);
    formdata.append("questionnaireID", quest_ID);
    formdata.append("questionNumber", quest_Number);
    formdata.append("media", 1);
    if (xhr) {
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    var outMsg = xhr.responseText;
                } else {
                    var outMsg = "There was a problem with the request. Error: " + xhr.status + " (" + xhr.statusText + ")"; //errror return  
                }
                alert(outMsg);
            }

        };
        xhr.open("POST", "addNew.php", false);
        xhr.send(formdata);
    }

    return false;
}
```

And here is the php.

```
function getExtention($str){
    return substr(strrchr($str,'.'),1);
}

if (isset($_POST["media"])){
        $tmp_file = $_FILES['inputFile']['tmp_name'];
        $target_file = $_POST["questionnaireID"] . "-" . $_POST["questionNumber"] . "." . getExtention(basename($_FILES['inputFile']['name']));
        $upload_dir = "Assets/Media";
        $path =  $upload_dir."/".$target_file;
        echo $path;
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, $path)) {
            $query = "insert into mediaDetails(available, mediaPath)";
            $query .= " values(1, '{$path}')";
            $result = execute($query);
            if($result){
                echo "Media added";
            }
        }else{
            echo "cannot move file";
        }

    }
```

that code work when I upload images and music, but not video.

why I can't upload video file?
when I upload video file, it returns nothing, (no text at all)...

even `echo $path` is not shown....

any alternative way??

any answer appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried changing the post_max_size?

Comment: yes I have, I changed int php.ini to 200M..

I always upload video below 200M